# Writing to a PHP file

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to write a basic error form to a file, but when I submit the file my PHP always crashes. I've tried some basic error fixes such as whether or not the if statement is occurring, if all the variables I'm using are not null, etc...

In my code all the string variables are valid an I am 100% certain they are not causing the error.

I've reduced it down through error testing to be the lines

```
 $destination  = fopen($filename,"w");
```

and

```
 $fclose($destination);
```

My code:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['name'] != "" && $_POST['email'] != ""){
    $filename = "message_" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ".txt";
    $issueType = "Type of issue: " . $_POST["issues"] . "\r\n";
    $submitter = "Submitted by: " . $_POST["name"];
    $email = "Email ID: " . $_POST["email"];
    $time = "Submitted at: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\r\n";
    $message = "Details: " . $_POST["details"];


    $destination = fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($destination,"Issue Alert!");
    fwrite($destination,$issueType);
    fwrite($destination,$submitter);
    fwrite($destination,$email);
    fwrite($destination,$time);
    fwrite($destination,$message);
    $fclose($destination);
  }
```

Any other code I'm implementing is irrelevant as I've cut off those as being points of error.

When I try this with basic, hard-coded strings I don't get any errors. All help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: you can't use colons as part of filenames and you have a syntax error for `$fclose()`.

Comment: If it crashed then I assume you are getting an error code, did you look in the php error log yet?

Comment: Late night questions are always such fun arn't they @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Thanks, I have an assignment due in a hour so I'm panicking and not thinking things through as I normally do

Comment: @Riggs meh; they keep me out of trouble. Seems I answered this puppy long time ago but the OP seems to want to be spoonfed with a simple rewrite.

Comment: You didn't post an answer that I could accept, my apologies I guess? I picked the most applicable one.

Comment: @HowardPearce You remember that answer that was given in your previous question, the one that contained a link to another Q&A which shows you how to check for errors? Well, you state in this one that there are no errors. I feel you weren't doing that which you would have been shown a few.

Comment: I didn't state that lol, if there were no errors I wouldn't be asking the question. I didn't see his comment, as the question was answered, he edited it after. Not really relevant to the comment but I appreciate the help. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your `$filename`, as you wrote

```
$filename = "message_" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ".txt";
```

because you can't use colon ( **':'** from **'`H:i:s`'**) in file name.

maybe you can try this:

```
$filename = "message_" . date('U') . ".txt";
```

you still have date-time information in your file name

But remember, if you have big traffic on your site, maybe you will get same file name in one second, and the previous existing file will overwrited

Comment: you missed something

Comment: sorry, what is it ?

Comment: it's in my first comment under the post

Comment: `$` before `fclose()` ? I think @Howard Pearce already noticed that. I just want to give alternative to keep using date-time information without colon in file name.

Comment: the dollar sign will immediately throw an undefined variable notice. That is a core php function